# Add a function to prototype

Tags: javascript

I made a function and added to a prototype but when I try to call it from element appears the error undefined is not a function.

```
function relMouseCoords(event){
var totalOffsetX = 0;
var totalOffsetY = 0;
var canvasX = 0;
var canvasY = 0;
var currentElement = this;

do{
    totalOffsetX += currentElement.offsetLeft - currentElement.scrollLeft;
    totalOffsetY += currentElement.offsetTop - currentElement.scrollTop;
}
while(currentElement = currentElement.offsetParent)

canvasX = event.pageX - totalOffsetX;
canvasY = event.pageY - totalOffsetY;

return {x:canvasX, y:canvasY}
 }

 HTMLCanvasElement.prototype.relMouseCoords = relMouseCoords;


        function onDocumentMouseMove( event ) {



            event.preventDefault();

var canvas= document.getElementsByTagName("canvas");


coords = canvas.relMouseCoords(); // **** undefined is not a function **** //
```

Comment: Is it because you declared relMouseCoords as a function with one parameter but you passed none?

Comment: @Heron, you can call a function and not pass it arguments. The variables inside the function will just be `undefined`

Comment: @PatrickEvans Didn't knew that. Thanks

Answer (score 5):

`getElementsByTagName` gets a nodeList, and a nodeList is not an instance of `HTMLCanvasElement` and as such doesn't have the added property.

Try to get an element instead

```
var canvas= document.getElementsByTagName("canvas")[0];
```

Also, you should be passing the `event` to the function

```
var coords = canvas.relMouseCoords(event);
```

[**FIDDLE**](http://jsfiddle.net/4hqvyb3v/1/)